# Join list into one string

Tags: arrays, swift, string, join

How to remove the first word of a string?

> 0.91% ABC DEF
>   0.922% ABC DEF GHI
>
> OUTPUT: ABC DEF / ABC DEF GHI

I tried

```
let test = str.split(separator: " ")[1...]
print(test)
print(test.joined(separator: " "))
```

Which gives me:

```
["ABC", "DEF"]
JoinedSequence<ArraySlice<Substring>>(_base: ArraySlice(["ABC", "DEF"]), _separator: ContiguousArray([" "]))
```

How can I print the JoinedSequence as a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
let str = "0.91% ABC DEF"
var parts = str.components(separatedBy: " ").dropFirst()

print(parts.joined(separator: " "))
```

Which prints:

> "ABC DEF\n"

Comment: Okay thats pretty easy, sorry :D. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Given a string

```
let text = "0.91% ABC DEF"
```

you can search for the ´index´ after the first space

```
if let index = text.range(of: " ")?.upperBound {
    let result = text.substring(from: index)
    print(result)
}
```